# How to scroll to a specific location when dealing with two pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 pages,the first one containing a list of questions and the next page containing a list of answers.What i need is when i click on the nth question in the first page,it should go to the next page and scroll to the answer of that nth question.This is how i have loaded the answer page.Could someone tell me a possible solution to scroll to the particular content using jquery.

```
  $('.question').live('click',function(){
       //some code
        $.ajax({
         success: function(data){
             //some code
        window.location.replace("target_url");
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use anchors in the second page. Which can be on the question id or answer I'd. And make the logic work on it.